# Copying subfolders with only first file to different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory with subfolders, each subfolders contains a couple images and I would like to copy the subfolder with only the first image from that subfolder (sorted alphabetically) to a different directory. I found a function that should manage to do this [via this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212176/copy-folders-and-subfolders-but-only-first-files-in-subfolders-with-python) but strangely enough this always copies the second image from the folder, instead of the first one.

From what I have seen on forums this should work, any ideas on what could cause this issue? I have tried playing with the amount of files to copy and I am able to copy all files from the source folder, except for the first one. It seems like it is simply ignored.

```
#1 Move first file from each subfolder to destination folder
p1 = r"D:\storage\source"
p2 = r"D:\storage\destination"

# limit of files to copy
N=1

for path, folders, files in os.walk(p1):

    # you might want to sort files first before executing the below
    for file_ in files[:N]:
    # if not files: continue

        src = os.path.join(path, file_)
        dst_path = path.replace(p1, '') + os.sep
        dst_folder = p2 + dst_path

        # create the target dir if doesn't exist
        if not os.path.exists(dst_folder):
            os.makedirs(dst_folder)

        # create dst file with only the first file
        dst = p2 + dst_path + file_

        # copy the file
        #print(src, dst)
        shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

Comment: Do you sort? ('# you might want to sort files first before executing the below'). `files[:1]` will split the array from the first element (position 0), to the second element (position 1), excluding the second element, so you should be getting what you need there. Put a breakpoint and examine the contents of the array to ensure it's in the order you expect / desire

Comment: Hi @Jonathan thanks for helping me out. Thanks to your advice I have been able to solve this issue, posted the final script in this post :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve this issue. With the following script the files first get sorted -> File with shortest name will sit in first position and then every folder with first file will be copied to a different directory.

```
#3 Move first file from each subfolder to destination folder
p1 = r"D:\storage\source"
p2 = r"D:\storage\destination"

    # limit of files to copy
    N=1
    
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(p1):
    
        # Files are sorted from shortest to longest names
        for file_ in sorted(files, key=len)[:N]:
        # if not files: continue
    
            src = os.path.join(path, file_)
            dst_path = path.replace(p1, '') + os.sep
            dst_folder = p2 + dst_path
    
            # create the target dir if doesn't exist
            if not os.path.exists(dst_folder):
                os.makedirs(dst_folder)
    
            # create dst file with only the first file
            dst = p2 + dst_path + file_
    
            # copy the file
            #print(src, dst)
            shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```